# Drag from any browser and drop in Qt app - set custom mime type data

Tags: qt, drag-and-drop, mime-types

Basically I am setting custom mime type data when i drag image from browser using javascript. Say ex, mime type is `text/x-my` and its data = `My data`.

But when I try to read it in Qt (when you drop image from browser to Qt window) I am not getting custom mime type `text/x-my` in Qt. However it is documented “*you can store custom mime type data in Qt*” see `QMimeData` Doc.
Now, interesting thing is, in Qt code you can set and get custom mime data but Qt is not reading custome mime data set from javascript.

```
QString str = "my data";
QMimeData *mimeData = new QMimeData;
mimeData->setData("text/x-my", str.toAscii());

QByteArray data = mimeData->data("text/x-my");
QString myString(data);
```

Above Qt code works just fine. Anybody have any idea why Qt is not reading custom mime type set from javascript ?

Thanks.

Comment: I assume you're already retrieving the `mimeData` from the Enter/Move/Drop Event ([`QDropEvent::mimeData`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qdropevent.html#mimeData)). From there, the best first step would be to see what format(s) your mimeData holds: try `qDebug`ing the contents of [`QMimeData::formats()`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qmimedata.html#formats)...

Comment: Yes.. but in debug I can't see format "text/x-my" in mime data which is set from javascript. (I'm using 4.8.2.)

Comment: A drag/drop event can contain mime data of multiple formats, hence why `QMimeData::data(...)` requires you to supply a mime format in order to retrieve data. Since you aren't able to retrieve any data, the first thing to check is whether the drag/drop event carries data of **any** format. Are you saying that `foreach(QString format, event->mimeData()->formats()) qDebug() << format;` doesn't print anything?

Comment: More on this, (I'm using 4.8.2.) Use [link](http://jsfiddle.net/cCunc/1/) fiddle and run the "dropsite" example from Qt\4.8.2\examples\draganddrop and check. You will not be able to see "text/x-example".